# Loading of the native code library for start0() native method in Thread class

Tags: java

I am looking for some in-depth explanation How Thread.start() internally invokes run() method.  I know that its my JVM which internally calls run() via start() method and when I started checking the source code of Thread class, I found these below code:

```
    public synchronized void start()
    {
        if(threadStatus != 0)
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
        group.add(this);
        start0();
        if(stopBeforeStart)
            stop0(throwableFromStop);
    }

    private native void start0();
```

Now as I can see that the start() is calling the native method start0() but I can not see any code related to the loading of native code library.

Please help me understanding the complete call flow.

Thanks,
Sandip

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205696/which-method-calls-run/39205770

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Java is open source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030814/is-java-an-open-source-programming-language). A small research can bring you the source code of the native code also. See, you can see yourself the flow. See [Where to find source code for java.lang native methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292629/where-to-find-source-code-for-java-lang-native-methods).

According to: [Java native method source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594046/java-native-method-source-code)  use [jdk7 source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7)

JDK 7's Thread.c: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/native/java/lang/Thread.c

Per my knowledge, looking up that native code to see what happens is not as fun as looking up java code you have seen till.

Because, though they encourage us not to use `native code`, they use it because `jdk` is differently released for different platforms. In most of the `jdk` sources we can see some native method declarations.

Comment: My "small research" led me here. Sensible question IMO.

Comment: @7SpecialGems ha ha... it often happens with stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at OpenJDK JVM sources: [Thread.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/178f954e1fd1/src/share/native/java/lang/Thread.c) and [jvm.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp) (`JVM_StartThread`)