# Which method calls run()?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
} }
```

According to [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

> The `Runnable` interface defines a single method, `run`, meant to contain the code executed in the thread. The Runnable object is passed to the Thread constructor.

So, **When we execute HelloRunnable, who calls the inside run method?**
In the `Thread` class, the `start` method looks like this:

```
public synchronized void start() {
     if (threadStatus != 0)
         throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
     group.add(this);
     start0();
     if (stopBeforeStart) {
         stop0(throwableFromStop);
     }
 }
```

From this code, we can see that the start method is not calling the `run()` method.

Comment: What about `start0` method, does it call `run` method? I mean, there's no magic, right? If `run` gets called, someone must be calling it :-)

Comment: what is *threadstatus*? stopBeforeStart?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight
start0() looks like this..
inline ` private native void More ...start0();`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, A thread's `run()` method is not called from anywhere inside the `start()` call.  If thread A calls `t.start()`, you wouldn't want `t.run()` to be called by thread A would you?  You'd want it to be called by a _different_ thread.  But, the `t.start()` call happens in thread A, and everything that is directly or indirectly called by `t.start()` happens in thread A.   The `t.run()` method gets called from somewhere _else_.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, P.S., If "magic" means "something you can't accomplish by writing pure Java code," then yes.  There _is_ magic.  As far as a pure Java programmer is concerned, system calls are magic.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is stated right in the [documentation of `start`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()):

> the Java Virtual Machine calls the `run` method of this thread

So, it is the native code in `start0` of the JVM that takes care of calling `run` in the newly created thread. (This is not quite unexpected, as launching a thread is very OS-specific and cannot be implemented in pure Java.)

*Note*: `start0` does not call `run` directly. Instead (on a high-level view, ignoring JVM-internal management), it instructs the operating system to create a new thread and let that thread execute `run`.

Just to clarify, here is a short description of the involved methods:

- `start` is the high-level function to start a new `Thread`.
- `start0` is the native method which creates a new Thread from the operating system and is responsible to ensure that `run` is called.
- `run` is the method defined in your `Runnable` classes. This method is what will be executed in the new thread. A `Thread` object in Java itself has no idea about the user code it should execute. This is the responsibility of the associated `Runnable` object.

Thus, when you call `Thread.start()`, the `run` method of the `Runnable` will automatically be called.

Of course, you can always call the `run` method of a `Runnable` explicitly:

```
HelloRunnable hr = new HelloRunnable();
hr.run();
```

However, this will, of course, *not* be executed in a separate thread, but block the execution.

Comment: Then when does JVM comes into the picture, like how JVM gets notified that start() has been called and now it is time to call the run() method? @martin

Comment: Ok, Thanks.
(Just curious) So is it possible to call the run() (pure java code) from the native code?

Comment: I notice that you are careful to say that `start0` "takes care of calling" `run()`, but you could be more explicit about the fact that it does not _call_ `run()`.  In fact, `run()`  is not called from _anywhere_ within the `start()` call.  It's called in a _different thread_.  That's a concept that a lot of noobs have trouble grasping.