# How run() method is getting invoked when I call Thread.start()?

Tags: java, multithreading

Though there are multiple posts explaining why we should call `start()` method instead of `run()` method directly my doubt is more like how JDK calls `run()` method internally when I call `start()`?

I went through the `Thread` class file and I'm not able to find the `run()` method getting invoked. Is it something getting invoked from native code? How is this happening?

```
public synchronized void start() {
        /**
         * This method is not invoked for the main method thread or "system"
         * group threads created/set up by the VM. Any new functionality added
         * to this method in the future may have to also be added to the VM.
         *
         * A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW".
         */
        if (threadStatus != 0)
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();

        /* Notify the group that this thread is about to be started
         * so that it can be added to the group's list of threads
         * and the group's unstarted count can be decremented. */
        group.add(this);

        boolean started = false;
        try {
            start0();
            started = true;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (!started) {
                    group.threadStartFailed(this);
                }
            } catch (Throwable ignore) {
                /* do nothing. If start0 threw a Throwable then
                  it will be passed up the call stack */
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you look into the ```start0()``` method? It seems the thread is defined as started after this method call

Comment: It's a native code so I'm not able to see the code.

Comment: The JavaDoc says: `Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the {@code run} method of this thread.`. I assume that happens in the native part of this method

Comment: Would you understand the native code if you saw it?

Comment: If it's C/C++ I will be able to.. If you can help me with the reference link I can give it a try :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which method calls run()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205696/which-method-calls-run)

Comment: No @QBrute. The below answer by Karol help me to understand better. I'm always reading somewhere somehow JVM does this but i haven't seen anywhere that's why i asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the native code sources since OpenJDK is an open source software.

For example [Github mirror of `Thread.c`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/Thread.c) class defines `Thread.start0()` native method as:

```
"start0",           "()V",        (void *)&JVM_StartThread},
```

where `JVM_StartThread` is defined in [`jvm.cpp`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b467629bd65b3823fd48f0cec90e9933b3fb3379/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvm.cpp#L2815) source file.

If you dig deeper into thread creation, which is OS specific, you will arrive to [`thread_entry()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b467629bd65b3823fd48f0cec90e9933b3fb3379/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvm.cpp#L2806) function which calls the `Thread.run()` method from within the native code:

```c
static void thread_entry(JavaThread* thread, TRAPS) {
  HandleMark hm(THREAD);
  Handle obj(THREAD, thread->threadObj());
  JavaValue result(T_VOID);
  JavaCalls::call_virtual(&result,
                          obj,
                          SystemDictionary::Thread_klass(),
                          vmSymbols::run_method_name(),
                          vmSymbols::void_method_signature(),
                          THREAD);
}
```