# get access to code behind Integer.toString() method in Java

Tags: java

How can I see the logic behind how this method converts an integer into a String.

According to this question, 
[Is java an open source programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030814/is-java-an-open-source-programming-language) It is. Therefore wouldn't I have access to all the classes?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your local zip file and unzip it:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\src.zip

```
public static String toString(int i) {
    if (i == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
        return "-2147483648";
    int size = (i < 0) ? stringSize(-i) + 1 : stringSize(i);
    char[] buf = new char[size];
    getChars(i, size, buf);
    return new String(buf, true);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer should I delete question ? I dont want to get too many downvotes lol

Comment: Your downvotes have been stable for 15 minutes, it's only 1 so I wouldn't bother. Deleting downvoted questions has more negative consequences than leaving them there. The question won't get that many views anymore probably, so there's little chance downvotes will be added. Keep the rules in mind for future questions though, minimal effort is required.

Answer (score 0):

Googling for `Integer.toString java code` gave me [this link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Integer.java?av=f#738) which contains

```
public String toString() {
    return toString(value);
}
```

You can also find details about `toString(int)` there.

Anyway code of standard Java classes is also placed in `src.zip` file in your JDK directory. You can also integrate your IDE like Eclipse with this file. This way you will be able to go to code of any method by clicking on it with pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

Check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

It contains all the methods for integer and how they can be used. If you're looking for a source code for the integer class, I suggest you decompile the jar files or simply search online for it.